# White screen of death in Dashboard after clean installation

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard, fatal-error

After some buggy updates of my websites from 4.5.3 to 4.6.1 I tried a clean installation of a new site on my server (FreeBSD 10.1, PHP 5.6.26, MariaDB 10.X, Apache 2.4)

Downloaded WP 4.1.6 from wordpress.org, put files where they belonged, created DB and configurated wp-config.php accordingly.
No additional themes or plugins were installed - no file (Apart from wp-config) altered

I have been doing this kind of work for the last 3 years successfully on other AND my  own server.
This time I just get a WSOF on the Dashboard, the update page and only half a page (to the sorting bar) when I want to add Themes through the dashboard.
The frontend shows perfectly and works flawlessly.

If I run e.g. the index.php from wp-admin on the console I get output: some warnings from WP core files and the obvious "Header allready sent" thanks to the warnings.

Any suggestions what has changed in 4.6.1 that could trip up the server - because I am pretty sure the WP core files work....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try enabling `debug mode` in `wp-config.php` to see errors to troubleshoot

Comment: Thank you and sorry for forgetting to mention that I already tried that - unfortunately no messages... not in log, nor showing

Comment: AH and my memory is set to 256M! - this too I forgot to mention :-(

Comment: Did you ever resolve your problem?  I'm having the same problem on a clean install.  (openSuse leap 42.1, PHP 5.5.14, MariaDB 10.1.19, Apache 2.4.16)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by a missing php package. I was able to resolve the issue and get the Dashboard (wp-admin) working by installing the package "php5-curl" and then restarting apache2.